# back from activity 3 to activity 1

Tags: android

I create applications with Eclipse using TextView which consists of some activity. when click the back button on activity 3 returned to activity 2 that contains an empty TextView. how to keep from Aktivity 3 can be directly to the activity 1

Answer (score 1):

override onbackpressed method in Activity3

In Activity 3

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this,
            Activity1.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);

 }
```

When you call activity 4 from 3 then remove set flag

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, Activity4.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks it's so help me. but i find a problem again , at activity 4 i didnt back to activity 3 who fill the listview but back to background in activity 3

Comment: when you call activity 4 then do not set flag ..check updated